# How to set the size of a panel inside a panel with null layout?

Tags: java, swing, null-layout-manager, setbounds

I have a main panel using a null layout and I want to add three more panel in it but I want those three panels to automatically resize upon loading of the main panel. I cant use layout managers since I will be dragging those three panels.

I tried this code but it doesnt work

```
pnlGrid.setBounds(514,11, pnlMain.this.getWidth()/3, pnlMain.this.getHeight());
```

I also tried

```
pnlGrid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pnlMain.this.getWidth()/3, pnlMain.this.getHeight()));
```

but still not good. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Often it is easier to do this by avoiding use of null layouts and instead using the layout managers. Why are you using null here in the first place? You can still drag the JPanels by use of the glasspane and similar.

Comment: You could create a custom layout manager.

Comment: Like what I indicated above, those panels will be draggable and I believe it's good to use null layout for that. I dont really want to change/apply layouts that will make it more difficult for me to build.

Comment: Have a look at this wonderful layout [The DragLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) by @camickr

Comment: *"dont really want to change/apply layouts that will make it more difficult for me to build."*  That is a strong case for avoiding a `null` layout.  Well put!

Comment: Just as a side note, preferred, minimum, maximum size is used mostly by layout managers. If your going to go down the path of not using them, then they have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) and update the `ComponentRestraints` when your dragging each panel. That way you can control exactly where they are and what their bounds are.

For example:

```
MigLayout layout;

public Constructor(){
   layout = new MigLayout();
   ...
   container.setLayout(layout);
}

public void onMouseDrag(JPanel panel, int newX, int newY){
   layout.setComponentConstraints(panel, "pos " + newX + " " + newY + ", w 100%/3, h 100%");
   container.validate(); // probably not necessary
}
```